# How to solve $x = ab^ x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

<sup>I'm not enough familiar with matrix manipulations, I hope this question is admissible here</sup>

---

Given vectors:
$$a=\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\\vdots \\a_n\end{bmatrix},\qquad
  b=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\\vdots \\b_n\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a^T b = 1$, I want to find the vector $x$ such that:

$$
x = a b^T x
$$

What are the symbolic steps to solve this equation? Thank you!

Comment: @LinAlg  thank you! Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach. Set $A=ab^T$. Then $A$ is idempotent: $$A^2=a(b^Ta)b^T=(b^Ta)ab^T=ab^T=A$$ The column space of any idempotent matrix is precisely equal to the set $$W=\{x:Ax=x\}$$ Here's a quick proof. If $x\in W$ then $$x=Ax\in \text{Col}(A)$$ which shows $W\subseteq \text{Col}(A)$. Meanwhile, if $x\in \text{Col}(A),$ find $v$ so that $Av=x$. Then $$Ax=A(Av)=A^2v=Av=x\in W$$ Hence $W=\text{Col}(A)$. The column space of $A=ab^T$ is clearly $\text{span}\{a\}$ as every column of $A$ is a multiple of $a$ and $b$ is non$-$zero. This means the solution set to $x=ab^Tx$ is precisely equal to the span of $\{a\}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a solution of the system $(I-ab^T)x=0$.

From the following two observations and the rank–nullity theorem, the null space of $I-ab^T$ is one dimensional:

1. Since $\text{rank}(I) \leq \text{rank}(I-ab^T) + \text{rank}(ab^T)$, $\text{rank}(I-ab^T) \geq n-1$.
2. Since $a^Tb=1$, $I-ab^T$ is [not invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), so $\text{rank}(I-ab^T) \leq n-1$.

So it suffices to find one nontrivial solution. The matrix $ab^T$ has eigenvector $a$ with eigenvalue $a^Tb=1$. Therefore $a$ is also an eigenvector of $ab^T-I$ (and $I-ab^T$) with eigenvalue $0$.